# Printing JSON-formatted data in Tcl

Tags: json, tcl

Hi I need to print the following as it is in tcl.

```
{'root':[{'name':'Test', 'val':'1'},{'name':'Test2', 'val':'3'}]}
```

when i do the following I get an error

```
puts "{'root':[{'name':'$name', 'val':'$val'},{'name':'$name', 'val':'$val'}]}"
```

Is there a way i can print those in tcl?

ok I tried this now:

```
puts "{'root':\[{'name':'$name', 'val':'$id'}"
```

but that doesnt work either

Comment: The main issue with producing JSON from Tcl is that the type systems don't fit with each other at all, which makes deciding how to serialize a value very difficult. (Going in the other direction is easy though.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that the '[' means that you want to execute something, so you need to escape it.

```
puts "{'root':\[{'name':'$name', 'val':'$val'},{'name':'$name','val':'$val'}\]}"
```

With those changes, should work.

Also, you can find more examples of how to manage JSON in tcl here: http://wiki.tcl.tk/13419

Comment: so u mean each time [ is encountered escape it with a backslash?

Comment: always that you don't want to execute what's inside the brackets. See more info here: http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/tutorial/Tcl5.html

Comment: Once both $val and $name values are defined, the previous line prints properly, but maybe you want something else ?

Comment: @user856753, note that using simple variable substitutions (`$var`) is not enough in your case: it will blow up if the substituted value contains a literal comma or more interesting things like `aaa'}, {`. So please pay very close attention to [that link](http://wiki.tcl.tk/13419) about JSON on the wiki as it discusses methods of properly escaping values constituting JSON objects.

Answer (score 1):

It's just

```
puts {{'root':[{'name':'Test', 'val':'1'},{'name':'Test2', 'val':'3'}]}}
```

That is, put the whole string between `{` and `}` to make it "literal".

More info is in [the tutorial](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/tutorial/Tcl4.html).

Comment: In fact I misread your question, not getting that the first snippet was merely a demonstration of what you want to get from the second one, sorry.  Anyway I think it's OK to not delete my attempt at answering as it deals with another possible use case for working with JSON.